# Return button id issue jquery

Tags: jquery, button

I am trying to return my button id:

```
$(document).on('click', 'button.btn.btn-primary', function() {
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

However, this returns `undefined`. When I tried `console.log(this)`, I get back a window object. I don't see this behavior with my other buttons that I return the `id` of.. can someone help?

Here is my html:

```
<tr class="child">
    <td class="child" colspan="8">
        <li data-dtr-offset-index-"7">
            <span class="dtr-title"></span>
            <span class="dtr-data">
                <button id="{{product_code}}" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Cart</button>
            </span>
        </li>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Additional context:

I am using jquery datatables. The above html is rendered when the table is in responsive mode.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: sorry, i copied the wrong html; i just updated it.

Comment: Are you using `angularjs`?

Comment: No, i'm using Handlebars

Comment: i added additional context in the question

Comment: Works fine here:  https://jsfiddle.net/kakvcs58/

Comment: I think `product_code` is undefined.

Comment: I inspected the source code and it's defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add it in an onload construct so the button exists

Please note that all the posted jsfiddle examples have the default `onload`  instead of `in head`

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on('click', 'button.btn.btn-primary', function() {
    console.log(this.id);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr class="child">
  <td class="child" colspan="8">
    <li data-dtr-offset-index- "7">
      <span class="dtr-title"></span>
      <span class="dtr-data">
                <button id="{{product_code}}" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Cart</button>
            </span>
    </li>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried jQuery solution?

```
$(document).on('click', 'button.btn.btn-primary', function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/yt22yq8h/

```
$(document).on('click', 'button.btn.btn-primary', function() {
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

This works fine for me .See the above fiddle.It does show the id in the console .

Comment: Because JSFiddle uses` onload` default